# grub version 2.04 not supporting USB keyboard

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have got two separate hard drives, one with Ubuntu newest version installed and other installed Windows 10.

After changing BIOS prioritizing to Ubuntu drive, I disable grub file `grub_timeout_style` then update the using `sudo update-grub` terminal command.

After update it's showing grub window but **not support to the keyboard**. Changing BIOS setting "Support to USB" does not work.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

An easy hack solved the same issue for me. I used the USB hub (not active) and it works now. Obviously it is a dirty hack and something is wrong here either with grub 2.04 or some other issues but for now it saves the situation.

Please read more here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/dsf29v/help_external_usb_keyboard_doesnt_work_at_grub/